# How do you ensure that a user's input only contains certain characters in python?

Tags: python, string

I need to make sure that the string that a user puts into the function contains only the letters "A", "T", "G", and "C".  If it contains any other characters I need to be able to return an error message.  For Example:  If the user inputs "ATTGACT" the string will advance through my function, but if the user inputs "ATTQWSCT"  the string will trigger an error message.  This is for a function involving DNA so the string can only contains those letters.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: This can be solved as `set(yourinput) <= {"A", "C", "T", "G"}`. This question will probably be closed as you didn't demonstrate any effort of solving the problem on your own - see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 5):

Really easy using `re`:

```
import re
pattern = "[^ACTG]+"
string = raw_input()
if re.findall(pattern, string):
    #error
else:
    #your code here
```

...Or default Python sets:

```
string = raw_input()
if set(string) <= {"A", "C", "T", "G"}:
    #error
else:
    #your code here
```

...Or iteration:

```
string = raw_input()
for i in string:
    if not (i in "ACTG"):
        #error

# Or, as @l4mpi said:
all(c in "ACTG" for c in string)
```

Comment: The set variant is in my opinion preferable; although `re` is probably faster for big inputs that contain a wrong character early on, as it will probably short circuit. Regarding the iteration method, that one can also be expressed as `all(c in "ACTG" for c in string)`.

Comment: @l4mpi, thanks, added it to the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
sequence="AATQWIC"
correct = "ATGC"

for each_char in sequence:
    if not each_char in correct:
        print "Error"
```